# Laravel rate limit throttle for /oauth/token Passport endpoint

Tags: php, laravel, rate-limiting, http-status-code-429

I'm trying to disable rate limiting for Passport's built-in `oauth/token` endpoint in Laravel 5.8, and I figured just removing the throttle middleware from api would do it:

```
'api' => [
    // 'throttle:60,1',
    'bindings',
],
```

But although this effectively disables rate limiting for every endpoint I've defined in my api routes file, it doesn't do it for `/oauth/token`, as if Passport has a default throttling setting.  So I just added the throttle middleware for that route in `AppServiceProvider` with an absurd number:

```
\Route::group(['middleware' => ['custom_provider', 'throttle:999999999,1']], function () {
    Passport::routes();
});
```

But when I test this I'm still getting 429 errors after a few requests for some reason:

```
429 Too Many Requests

X-RateLimit-Limit →9999999999
X-RateLimit-Remaining →9999999935
x-ratelimit-reset →1567108098
```

So I'd prefer to just disable this entirely.  Any ideas how to disable it for Passport routes specifically?

Comment: Shouldn't `Passport::routes();` be in the `AuthServiceProvider` boot method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because passport doesn't use `api` middleware, but `throttle` one directly on that route.
You can see that in the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/7.0/src/RouteRegistrar.php#L73):

```php
// This is how passport register that route
$this->router->post('/token', [
    'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
    'as' => 'passport.token',
    'middleware' => 'throttle',
]);
```

You can override that route be defining it yourself before passport register his route. To do that I think the most convenient way is to hook up into the `Passport::routes()` method:

```php
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    $router->forAuthorization();

    Route::post('/token', [
        'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
        'as' => 'passport.token',
    ]);
    // This function would trigger the internal /token route registration
    $router->forAccessTokens();

    $router->forTransientTokens();
    $router->forClients();
    $router->forPersonalAccessTokens();
});
```

Note that you might as well do this instead if you need all of the passport routes:

```php
Passport::routes(function ($router) {
    Route::post('/token', [
        'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
        'as' => 'passport.token',
    ]);
    $router->all();
});
```

You can check if the route has been registered correctly by doing `php artisan route:list` in a console windows from the root of your project

Comment: Thanks this works, but $router->forAccessTokens(); or  $router->all(); should go before Route::post('/token'.. to override the route. My  laravel is v6.13.1.